# How can i create object in Firestore Database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

"I am trying to create a database for my mobile app. I have already created a Users collection with information about the user, and a Questions collection for the questions. Inside Questions, I save the text, answer, time, and other values for each question. Similarly, in Users, I save contact information for each user.

Now, I want to save the success rate of my users for a question. For example, a string like WRWRR shows me that for question ID 3s3NEa3lb9jbp2PWAthc, the user has tried 5 times with 2 wrong and 3 correct answers.

I believe that I have to add a collection inside each user where I can save this information. The problem is that I can't connect the string to the question ID.

One small solution I found is what I did with bookmarks: /USERS/PF7EEUB00SPcKbMeCgWKHvepqEP2/USER_DATA/BOOKMARKS/5MsC0TGwfi50iR8teD0Q. Inside Users, I created User-data and added the IDs of the questions to the BOOKMARKS collection.

However, I can't do the same because I don't want to save just the ID of the question, but also the string (WRWRR).

Can anyone help me?"
[Firestore preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVsbN.png)
[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAbFy.png)

In the second picture i want somehow to have inside the Questions History an object? with the String and the Question ID. I am not sure if object is the correct word.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What is the problem in saving `5Ms...D0Q + WRWRR`?

Comment: Hello thank for your time.  I dont know how to save that. I can only sabe the ID of the Question as i did in Bookmarks. and if i save them separately it does not really work. I need a way to connect them or save them as an object both together

Comment: "it does not really work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors? Besides that, since those objects are string, why not concatenate them?